# Removing popup programmatically does not work in MapLibre JS

Tags: javascript, popup, maplibre-gl

Removing programmatically a popup does not work.

Popup created OK, as:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {new maplibregl.Popup().setLngLat(e.lngLat).setHTML('MODIFICATIONS').addTo(map);});
```

Deleting programmatically as:

```
map.on('CloseButton', () => {new maplibregl.Popup().remove();});
```

Does not work on map.fire(`CloseButton`);

Answer (score 0):

Create the popup globally so you can can access it during any event or function.

```
let popup_tobe_closed=new maplibregl.Popup();
map.on('click', function(e) {popup_tobe_closed.setLngLat(e.lngLat).setHTML('MODIFICATIONS').addTo(map);});
```

then you can call wherever you desire

```
popup_tobe_close.remove();
```